# MongoDB:: Efficient Compound index on MultiKey field with sorting

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, wiredtiger

i'm trying to make a compound index on a multi-key field be performant on sorting, but i can't seem to figure it out. using mongo 3.6 with wiredtiger here. my documents look like this (removed everything that's not being queried nor is in the index):

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
  something: {
    nested: [{_id: ObjectId()}, {_id: ObjectId()}, {_id: ObjectId()}]
  },
  another: {
    thing: {
      _id: ObjectId()
    }
  }
}
```

there are a few million documents in the collection and i've got the following indices:

```
{ "_id": 1 }
{ "something.nested._id": 1, "another.thing._id": 1, "_id": -1 }
{ "something.nested._id": 1, "_id": -1, "another.thing._id": 1 }
{ "_id": -1, "something.nested._id": 1, "another.thing._id": 1 } # this one only exists in a non-production system with far less documents
```

i'm trying to do a query like this (ideal case):

```
db.getCollection('whatever').find({"something.nested._id": ObjectId("5b88937a98162d5595b00000"), "another.thing._id": {"$ne": ObjectId("5b88937a98162d5595b00000")}} ).sort(_id: -1).limit(51)
```

explain tells me that it's doing an backward `IXSCAN` on the `_id` index, then a `FETCH` with a filter on `"something.nested._id"` and `"another.thing._id"`. this results on many many documents being scanned before it finds enough to satisfy the limit. it's not using any of the indices that contain `"something.nested._id"`. 
on the staging system i've tried a compound index that has the `_id` as prefix (i've read that somewhere), but it's not the optimal choice for the planner and if i force it i have a similar result.

the only thing that improves this query in any way is to get rid of the `.sort({_id: -1})` (it's actually superfast then), but the natural sorting might be wrong, so i can't really use that (even though in all my test cases it happened to be correct).

so is there an efficient index that i'm just missing or did we get ourselves into a corner with our data model?